Tortoisesvn 1.14 client not connecting to older (1.8) server
The IT system keeps updating my TortoiseSVN client automatically to version 1.14.29673.   This update causes my connection to the repository server (version 1.8 or earlier) to fail with the following error:

Update
C:<LOCAL PATH> from https:///svn//trunk
Unable to connect to a repository at URL
'https:///svn//trunk'
Error running context: An error occurred during SSL communication

The repository is working.  If I uninstall 1.14 and reinstall v1.8, I can update and work with my repository.   Is there some client setting I should look into to correct this, so that I can use the updated client version?
I am getting tired of having to undo the automatic updates, downgrading does work, but the IT system keeps updating it (out of security concerns, I am sure).  I just don't know enough about the guts of TortoiseSVN to know where to start with it.

Wouldn't the appropriate solution be to update the repository to the newer version? It solves the problem with ITs forced updates, and gives you bug fixes and new features of the newer version as well.

@KenWhite I don't have admin access to the original server, although that may be the end option.   I am an independent consultant/contractor and so have limited authority to do much out of my local machine.   I would prefer a local solution (change some svn setting, for example) if that is an option.

As the error refers specifically with SSL communication, I'd suspect that the newer client version has upgraded to a newer (and more secure) version of the SSL libraries. I'm not sure that you can do much about that on your end. Also, I've learned from experience that fights with corporate IT are always losing battles - at some point, someone is going to notice that you're reverting the updates. Your best bet is to reach out to IT and explain the issue, so that they can either upgrade the server or give you an exception from the update.

If I remember correctly https svn servers were implemented usually not as stand-alone server but as plugin for Apache2. If this is the case the used openssl version and/or SSL config of Apache is the problem. For "lifting up" an old server to modern TLS versions you can consider using a recent version of a reverse proxy like nginx.
